# Updating a json file using jq while keep the exact same input (except changed value)

Tags: arrays, json, jq

To keep things simple, I have that file.js:

```
{
    "devices": [
      {
        "label": "label1",
        "percent": 10
      },
      {
        "label": "label2",
        "percent": 20
      }
    ]
 }
```

Since I browsed Google and StackOverflow a lot, I actually know how to update, let's say, the label2 from 20% to 50% :

```
jq '.devices[] | select(.label == "label2").percent = 50' file.json
```

But here's the ouput:

```
{
  "label": "label1",
  "percent": 10
}
{
  "label": "label2",
  "percent": 50
}
```

The devices object (?) is not there anymore.

I'd like to find a way to keep the exact same input format.
I guess I should rid of the pipe, but I don't know how.
I've browsed Google and I found the
to_entries / with_entries / from_entries, that seem to keep the whole thing, but I don't know how to merge eveything together.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the traversal and filtering all part of the assignment's LHS using parentheses:

```bash
jq '(.devices[] | select(.label == "label2").percent) = 50' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1VVyxygosCJ)

Alternatively, [update](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment%3A%7C%3D) `|=` to a `map` of the whole `.devices` array:

```bash
jq '.devices |= map(select(.label == "label2").percent = 50)' file.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/fxV9xDeuCJj)

Output:

```json
{
  "devices": [
    {
      "label": "label1",
      "percent": 10
    },
    {
      "label": "label2",
      "percent": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Damn, I've tried the parentheses but I put them around the whole expression, including the =50! I get it now. Thank you very much!